# Django multibase administration site

Tags: python, django

I newbe in Django, so excuse me for question, but I can't find solution.

I try to work with multibases. f.ex. (sqlite3). First of it is default (in file db.sqlite3) and second is 'depend' in file depend.sqlite3.

I set something in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'depend': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'depend.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

and after:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database 'depend' > models.py
```

and change column-key, I have:

```
from django.db import models

class AllFiles(models.Model):
    db_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
...
```

my router.py states now:

```
class AuthRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'depend':
            return 'depend'
        return None
...
```

and in settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [ 'router.AuthRouter',
                    ]
```

and next I add my 3 tables from new DB into admin-site with:

```
admin.site.register(models.AllFiles)
admin.site.register(models.ImportingDict)
admin.site.register(models.InputDir)
```

when server (localhost:8000) is running, and admin is logged, I have in admin-view (http://localhost:8000/admin/)
3 new position with 3 new tables, but when try do something with one of them, get:

```
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

no such table: all_files
```

what I missing? what is wrong?

Should I register router? how do it? Any example pls?

Pls help me.

Comment: Did you migrate? `python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes: (venv)wiks@asus:~/Dokumenty/projects/wiks_depend/mysite$ python manage.py makemigrations
   No changes detected

Comment: What about `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: `python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply. ` and after `python manage.py migrate --database=depend` i got: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "all_files" already exists`

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem / mistake was in app label in route.py file...

was:

```
if model._meta.app_label == 'depend':
```

should be:

```
if model._meta.app_label == 'app':
```

admin works perfect :-)

Thank you for help!